# Standard errors of Monte Carlo plus linear combination

Tags: estimation, standard-deviation, standard-error, monte-carlo, derivative

I'm using Monte Carlo to estimate some quantity $V(x)$. To get an approximation of $V'(x)$ I would use the following
$$
V'(x)\approx\frac{V(x+h)-V(x-h)}{2h}
$$ so I can simply evaluate it with two estimations and get the approximation. My question is, given the standard errors of $V(x+h)$ and $V(x-h)$, what should be the SE of $V'(x)$?

What about the SE for the second derivative:

$$
V''(x)\approx\frac{V(x+h)-2V(x)+V(x-h)}{h^2}
$$

Comment: The main issue is that the finite difference approximation to the derivative can be quite a poor approximation to $V^\prime(x)$. One can thus find the SE of the RHS but this does not tell anything about  $V^\prime(x)$. For instance, confidence intervals have no guarantee to include   $V^\prime(x)$.

Comment: I see, so would you say it's meaningless to consider the CI for $V'(x)$ if I compute it this way?

Comment: It might be far better to estimate $V^\prime$ in each MC iteration: that will correctly account for the (strong possibility) that $V(x+h)$ and $V(x-h)$ are highly positively correlated.  This also reveals that, at a minimum, you need to have information about the covariance of $V(x+h)$ and $V(x-h)$ in addition to their standard errors.